# Sending Email regarding confirmation to others from iPhone application

Tags: iphone

I am developing an application in which there is form to fill containing username, age, email id, phone no. All these are in labels.

When user click on confirmation button i want an automatic email is send to the email address specified in the form giving details of the confirmation. This all process should be automatic and hidden from user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid you are out of luck. MessageUI Framework  does not support automatic emails. You can fill up To, subject and body using this frame work, but the user has to press the send button to send the email.This is a security feature of ios to prevent spam emails. If you really need automatic email functionality, you can sent the captured info to your server and send an email from server side, but make sure you are handling the user data securely.

Comment: If i put send button on my application confirmation view and user press that button then rest of the information can send automatically? like user has not to fill subject and body. it automatically contains subject and in body all information regarding the form like username etc.

Comment: Nope. You dont have much controll over the modal view presented. You may take a look at the below tutorial. http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-in-app-email/